# Change list of images opacity on hover - css

Tags: css, hover, opacity

My HTML is:

```
<ul>
    <li>
      <div>
          <img>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <div>
          <img>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
       <div>
           <img>
      </div>

    </li>
<ul>
```

while hover the `ul` I would like that all the images will be with opacity 1  and on mouse leave return to opacity 0.5

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `hover` property on the target element, and the effect `opacity` on the affected element.

```css
ul img {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

ul:hover img {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" />
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" />
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" />
    </div>

  </li>
  <ul>
```

Comment: thx 
How can I make one of the image to opacity 1 by defualt event the ul is opacity 0.5 .  for exmaple for active image after click

Comment: Just change `:hover` to `:active` and it will work. For more list go [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Use css hover.

```
ul {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

ul:hover {
  opacity: 1
}
```

In javascript, you need event handler `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

Answer (score 1):

You can see it working here

```css
ul {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

ul:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
      <div>
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/csS/img_forest.jpg" alt="Forest" width="170" height="100">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <div>
          <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/csS/img_mountains.jpg" alt="Mountains" width="170" height="100">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
       <div>
           <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/csS/img_fjords.jpg" alt="Fjords" width="170" height="100">
```

More info in [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css_image_transparency.asp)

Answer (score 0):

give a class for div box-hover

```
  $( "li" ).hover( function() { 
$(this).find('.box-hover').fadeIn(100); }, 
function() { $(this).find('.box-hover').fadeOut(100); 
} );
```

Comment: There is no mention of jQuery in the question, yet you have used it.

Answer (score 0):

you can change this because img is the child of ul so try this

```
ul img {
opacity: 0.5;
transition: 250ms all ease-in-out; // transition for better looks
}

ul:hover img {
opacity : 1;
}
```

You can change the transition time from 250 ms to any more it more smoother but slower the animation of fade-in and fade-out would be